# Access a model method from another model in Cake

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm not sure if I'm using the MVC architecture correctly so go easy on me if I'm going wrong.

I have a model `Account` that grabs a load of valuations from a `Holding` model. These 2 models are linked as `Account` hasMany `Holdings`.

In my `Account` model I have a function that retrieves the sum of the holdings from the account and arranges it in a `$date=>$value` type array.

I have another, separate, model called `FxRate` whose table is a load of FX rates and dates. In my `Account` model I want to retrieve an array of fx rates by running a find on the `FxRate` table so I can convert the valuations array I retrieved earlier.

`FxRate` is not linked to either of the other models and I can't seem to `find` any data from it from within my `Account` model. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in your Model file you can use this:

```
App::uses('FxRate', 'Model');
$FxRate = ClassRegistry::init('FxRate') // and not $FxRate =  new FxRate(), see comments;
$FxRate->find('all');
```

in your controller instead you can use `loadModel`

```
$this->loadModel('FxRate');
$this->FxRate->find('all');
```

Comment: You should never instantiate models directly! Use [`ClassRegistry::init()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init) instead.

Comment: so the right syntax should be `$FxRate =  ClassRegistry::init('FxRate')`? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's how it should look like, yes.

Comment: That works when I put the `$FxRate = ClassRegistry::init('FxRate')` inside a method of `Account` but if I try and define it as a property of `Account` (ie outside a method: `public $FxRate = ClassRegistry::init('FxRate');`) it gives me an 'unexpected "("' error

Comment: @harryg because that's invalid syntax in PHP, only constant values are allowed for [property initialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), ie values that can be evaluated at compile time. If you want to assign dynamic values, then you must explicitly do that at runtime, for example in the class' constructor.